# Why do I hear an noise when I alt+tab away from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, noise, vimperator

I'm using a few 'normal' Firefox Addins but I am using Vimperator which to me seems like the most likely suspect.

Comment: What kind of noise? Not the Internet Explorer "click" is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the Vimperator beep, you can try disabling it by putting the following file in your .vimperatorrc file:

```
javascript liberator.beep = function () { return false; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the plugin, restart firefox, and see if it still happens.